# How to determine the length of a YouTube video?

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api

This one is a simple question, but I have no experience in this topic, so I would like to use your help. So, the question is (as the title says):

**How can I determine the length(duration in sec) of a YouTube video?**

It would be great if this information is available from HTML source. But any other idea is good, I'm currently just brainstorming about a new application, where the duration of the videos is strongly important.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javascript youtube api.
You can find our more on this link
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information

Where you have method on player:

`player.getDuration()`