# I want to test a YouTube video's length with javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube

I am working in WordPress. I put a YouTube video in it and I would like to test the length of it. But the WordPress put the iFrame many div and script tags into the iFrame and I can't find which one I have to use. I will attach a picture of the WordPress code. What have I tested to get the video's length? 
[image]

Here is my javascript code, this is still working if I use a video from my storage.

```
addVideoAdTimer = () => {
    // Video timer
    let videoblock = document.getElementsByClassName('phone-video-1')[0]
    let videoblock2 = document.getElementsByClassName('phone-video-2')[0]
    //Video 1
    if(videoblock || videoblock2) {
        let firstTimerBlock = document.getElementById('first-video-timer')
        let video1 = videoblock.getElementsByClassName('elementor-widget-video')[0]
        let firstTimerInit = firstTimerBlock.innerText = fancyTimeFormat(0)
        firstTimerBlock.getElementsByTagName('p').innerHTML = firstTimerInit
        video1.addEventListener('timeupdate', getAdVideo1Duration)

        function getAdVideo1Duration() {
            let currentTime;
            let firstTimerAdBlock;
            let firstTimerInitPlay = fancyTimeFormat(Math.round(video1.currentTime))
            if (firstTimerInitPlay >= '00:00:03' && firstTimerInitPlay <= '00:00:05') {
                    currentTime = fancyTimeFormat(Math.round(video1.currentTime - 2 )) 
                    firstTimerAdBlock = firstTimerBlock.innerText = currentTime
            } else if(firstTimerInitPlay == '00:00:00') {
                firstTimerAdBlock = firstTimerBlock.innerText = fancyTimeFormat(0)
            }
            firstTimerBlock.getElementsByTagName('p').innerHTML = firstTimerAdBlock
        }

        //Video2
        let secondTimerBlock = document.getElementById('second-video-timer')
        let video2 = videoblock2.getElementsByClassName('elementor-widget-video')[0]
        let secondTimerInit = secondTimerBlock.innerText = fancyTimeFormat(0)
        secondTimerBlock.getElementsByTagName('p').innerHTML = secondTimerInit
        video2.addEventListener('timeupdate', getAdVideo2Duration)

         function getAdVideo2Duration() {
            let secondTimerInitPlay = secondTimerBlock.innerText = fancyTimeFormat(Math.round(video2.currentTime))
            let secondTimer =  secondTimerBlock.getElementsByTagName('p')
            secondTimer.innerHTML = secondTimerInitPlay
        }
    }
}
 fancyTimeFormat = (time) =>
{   
    // Hours, minutes and seconds
    var hrs = Math.round(time / 3600);
    var mins = Math.round((time % 3600) / 60);
    var secs = Math.round(time % 60);

    var currentTime = "";
    if (hrs > 0) {
        currentTime +=  hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" + mins : mins)  + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" + secs : secs);
    } 
    currentTime += "00:" + (mins < 10 ? "0" + mins : mins)  + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" + secs : secs);
    return currentTime;
}
```

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635984/how-to-determine-the-length-of-a-youtube-video and also available with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086260/youtube-player-api-how-to-get-duration-of-a-loaded-cued-video-without-playing-i

Comment: Try: `document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-time-duration")[0].innerText` as I'm not sure if that frame has exactly what's on youtube

Comment: I tried all of the 2 answers but none of them are working in my code.